# How can I prevent these memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I met huge problem with memory leaks and I don't know where to put that "delete" to get rid of them. Below is part of my code, and there is a full one: https://pastebin.com/Wtk83nuH.

```
string* startowa(int& rozmiar)
{
rozmiar = 5;
string* tablica = new string[rozmiar];

for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
    tablica[i] = "text";
return tablica;
}

string* plusx(string* tab, int& rozmiar)
{
string tekst = "something";
string* tablica_3 = new string[rozmiar];
tablica_3[rozmiar - 1] = tekst;
for (int i = 0; i<rozmiar - 1; i++)
    tablica_3[i] = tab[i];

return tablica_3;
}

string* minusx(string* tab, int& rozmiar)
{
string* tablica_3 = new string[rozmiar];
for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
    tablica_3[i] = tab[i];

return tablica_3;
}

int main()
{
int wybor = 1, rozmiar = 1;
string *tablica = startowa(rozmiar);

while (wybor != 55) {
    cin >> wybor;
    if (wybor == 1) {
        rozmiar++;
        tablica = plusx(tablica, rozmiar);
    }
    if (wybor == 6) wybor = 55;
    else {
        rozmiar--;
        tablica = minusx(tablica, rozmiar);
    }
    // there were other "ifs" but its just a part of the code
}
for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
    cout << tablica[i] << endl;

delete[] tablica;
cin >> wybor;

getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stupid, but accurate, answer: By not using raw dynamic memory. Not seeing anything in there that needs it with a quick glance.

Comment: Never use `new` in C++.

Comment: Replace dynamic arrays with std::vector.  And if you still need pointers replace raw pointers with std::unique_ptr.  new/delete are rarely needed now in C++ and you should think before you use them.

Comment: Paraphrasing Bjarne himself: If you have a `delete`, you probably have a bug. If you have a naked `new`, you probably need a `delete`.

Answer (score 2):

The memory leak is your least problem in that source code. In fact, you don't need heap allocations at all in your example.

Here are some fast improvements:
- use "std::string" instead of just string, I guess you are using "using namespace std"
- do not return a pointer to string, you can just declare a string and return it
- do not use a reference to an int as a function parameter if you are not  returning it
- use const as much as you can
- replace "string *" with "const string&" if you are not returning it
- do not allocate string on heap (with new), instead declare it on stack
- use vectors

You can use this [great site](https://isocpp.org/faq) and Scott Meyers books for other C++ good practices.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent memory leaks like that, avoid manual memory management. There are a lot of tools available to you.

For example, take your string array:

```
string* startowa(int& rozmiar) {
    rozmiar = 5;
    string* tablica = new string[rozmiar];

    // ...
}
```

This should be replaced by `std::vector`. And since a vector keep track of it's size, you don't need to pass the size as reference:

```
 std::vector<std::string> startowa() {
    // ...
    std::vector<std::string> tablica(5);

    // ...
}
```

Then, your function that operates on the array should take the vector by reference to about copies, and return another vector. Since a vector already has a function that insert a new element, your `plusx` function becomes this:

```
void plusx(std::vector<std::string>& tab) {
    std::string tekst = "something";
    tab.emplace_back(std::move(tekst));
}
```

And your `minusx` function becomes that:

```
void minusx(std::vector<std::string>& tab) {
    tab.pop_back();
}
```

By the way, with a vector, you can completely remove your `startowa` function by replacing the call in your main by this:

```
// Was `string *tablica = startowa(rozmiar);`
std::vector<std::string> tablica(5, "text");
```

Since `std::vector` manages it's memory itself, you don't need to delete it anywhere.

---

If you don't want to use vector, you can alway use `std::unique_ptr<std::string[]>`. The only difference in you code would be to send `tablica.get()`  to your functions, and use `std::make_unique<std::string[]>(rozmiar)` instead of `new std::string[rozmiar]`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer [is use `std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). For example:

```
vector<string> startowa(int& rozmiar)
{
    rozmiar = 5;
    vector<string> tablica(rozmiar);

    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
        tablica[i] = "text";
    return tablica;
}
```

Note the return by value. Don't fall into the trap of thinking you're saving processing time by [returning by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). That `vector` [goes out of scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) and is destroyed at the end of the function. With a returned reference the best you can hope for is the caller receiving a load of garbage and crashing before any damage can be done.

A decent compiler will eliminate the copying when you return the `vector` by value, and if the compiler decides that it cannot, [`std::move` will take care of that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

`vector` also knows how big it is, eliminating the need for `rozmiar`.

Now... What went wrong? Let's look at the code

```
int main()
{
    int wybor = 1, rozmiar = 1;
    string * tablica = startowa(rozmiar);
```

`startowa` allocated an array of strings and stored a pointer to the array in `tablica`.

```
    while (wybor != 55)
    {
        cin >> wybor;
        if (wybor == 1)
        {
            rozmiar++;
            tablica = plusx(tablica, rozmiar);
```

`plusx` allocated a new array of strings, a pointer to which has been returned and written over the pointer returned by `startowa`. `startowa`'s array is now effectively lost, leaked, as it is next to impossible to find again to `delete[]`.

We would need to `delete[] tablica;` before making the assignment. Clearly we can't do this before calling `plusx` as `tablica` is a parameter, so we need to store a temp.

```
            string * temp = plusx(tablica, rozmiar);
            delete[] tablica;
            tablica = temp;
```

But what if something unexpected happens and [an exception is thrown](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/exceptions)? The code never hits the `delete[]` and BOTH allocations are lost. `vector` handles all this for you.

And back to the code

```
        }
        if (wybor == 6)
            wybor = 55;
        else
        {
            rozmiar--;
            tablica = minusx(tablica, rozmiar);
```

Same problem and solution as above.

```
        }
        // there were other "ifs" but its just a part of the code
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
        cout << tablica[i] << endl;

    delete[] tablica;
```

One of an in-determinant number of allocations is released here. The rest are lost.

```
    cin >> wybor;

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```